# Saving Large Temp Tables into Perm tables, SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, performance, data-migration

Am writing some processes to pre-format certain data for another downstream process to consume. The pre-formatting essentially involves gathering data from several permanent tables in one DB, applying some logic, and saving the results into another DB.

The problem i am running into is the volume of data. the resulting data set that i need to commit has about 132.5million rows. The commit itself takes almost 2 hours. I can cut that by changing the logging to simple, but it's still quite substantial (seeing as the generating of the 132.5 million rows into a temp table only takes 9 mins).

I have been reading on best methods to migrate large data, but most of the solutions implicitly assumes that the source data already resides in a single file/data table (which is not the case here). Some solutions like using SSMS task option makes it difficult to embed some of the logic applications that i need.

Am wondering if anyone here has some solutions.

Comment: Sorry, that soudns totally like "get a server properly sized to the task". Seems like something is too slow, and needs better hardware.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you're on SQL Server 2014 or later the temp table is not flushed to disk immediately.  So the difference is probably just disk speed.

Try making the target table a [Clustered Columnstore](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/indexes/columnstore-indexes-overview?view=sql-server-ver15) to optimize for compression and minimize IO.